# Looking for an example of a function which has (at least) two distinct left inverses

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> Looking for an example of a function which has (at least) two distinct left inverses

I know that F has a left inverse if for $f: A \rightarrow B$ and $g: B \rightarrow A$ follows such that $g(f(x)) = I_A$ = $x, \; \forall \, x\in A$

I'm pretty sure to have two distinct left inverses I need to have another function $h$ where $h: B \rightarrow A$ and $h(f(x)) = I_A$ = $x, \; \forall \, x\in A$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $A=\{1,2\}$ and $B=\{1,2,3\}$. Let be $f:A\to B$ and $f(x)=x$ for $x\in A$. A left inverse $g$ of $f$ must hold $g(1)=1$ and $g(2)=2$, but $g(3)$ can be $1$ or $2$. This gives exactly two possibilities for $g$.

Of course, if $A$ and $B$ are bigger, there can be many more possibilities. Note, nonetheless, that $f$ must be injective and its left inverses must be surjective.

Comment: "but g(3) can be 1 or 2" Did you you mean "but g(3) **can't** be 1 or 2"

Answer (score 3):

Why not try $A$ as a single point and $B$ as something bigger? Then you should be able to mess around with $g$ some and not change anything about $g \circ f$.

Answer (score 2):

Consider $f(n)=2n$ for $n\in\Bbb Z$ and $g(n)=\lfloor \frac n2\rfloor$, $h(n)=\lceil\frac n2 \rceil$. Then $g(f(n))=h(f(n))=n$ but $g\neq h$.

Answer (score 2):

$f(x)=e^x$, $g(x)=\begin{cases}\ln x&x>0\\0&x\le0\end{cases}$, $h(x)=\begin{cases}\ln x&x>0\\1&x\le0\end{cases}$ (where all functions have domain $\mathbb R$)